# Google Contact custom field with zapier

Tags: google-contacts-api, zapier

I have a website with a contact form. This form is connected with Zapier to add all the info to my Google Contact. This works pretty good, except for the Custom field.

I contacted Zapier about this issue, but it looks everything works fine from their end. Also, I got an output from what happend.

Here is a screenshot from the custom field I made and the field with the value (in the screenshot it is "Option One", but this is "gezin" in the end). So I used the correct fields and value.

In the second screenshot, the custom field and value are switched. Is this a bug?

So I contacted Zapier about this issue and they send the output from Zapier themselfs.

---

**They send me this answer:**

I wanted to be 100% sure about this though, I also went through our logging here to see the confirmation Google sent back when they added this customer: https://cdn.zapier.com/storage/files/fde1f499ef4ddab4770df713feedf1b5.txt

If you scroll all the way to the bottom, you'll see Google successfully verified the correct key (or field) and value pair there. My hunch here is either the fields might be switched within the Google Contacts itself, would you mind double checking to see if that might be the case? Beyond that it, it's possible this might be a bug on Google's end and their support team will be able to assist you. The .txt file above would be able to serve as a confirmation that Google received our data as you intended. Please let me know what their thoughts are, we'll be able to help out where we can.

Not sure if the .txt is readable so here is a copy of that in the text.

I hope somebody could help me out a bit? Greets Stefan Segers

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpXzE.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yflCk.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9TVX.png
```

Credentials are censored and data may be formatted and/or truncated.

```
permalink: /messages/graylog_11723/90131e24-a019-11ea-8054-0ebbdeefd93f
timestamp: 2020-05-27T12:57:04.000Z
```

---

### REQUEST

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/c1653511760700496166?personFields=addresses%2Cbiographies%2Cbirthdays%2CemailAddresses%2Cevents%2Cmemberships%2Cmetadata%2Cnames%2Corganizations%2CphoneNumbers%2Cphotos%2Crelations%2Curls%2CuserDefined

user-agent: Zapier
Authorization: Bearer :censored:173:0bdd981124:
```

---

### RESPONSE

```
200

content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
content-encoding: gzip
date: Wed, 27 May 2020 12:57:03 GMT
server: ESF
cache-control: private
x-xss-protection: 0
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
alt-svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
connection: close
transfer-encoding: chunked

{
  "resourceName": "people/c1653511760700496166",
  "etag": "%EhQBAj0DBQYHCT4LPwwQQBMVFjU3LhoEAQIFByIMRlZwOUxZeHdmTFE9",
  "metadata": {
    "sources": [{
      "type": "CONTACT",
      "id": "16f2742f887bd926",
      "etag": "#FVp9LYxwfLQ=",
      "updateTime": "2020-05-27T12:57:03.686Z"
    }],
    "objectType": "PERSON"
  },
  "names": [{
    "metadata": {
      "primary": true,
      "source": {
        "type": "CONTACT",
        "id": "16f2742f887bd926"
      }
    },
    "displayName": "Aadje Plakplaatje",
    "familyName": "Plakplaatje",
    "givenName": "Aadje",
    "displayNameLastFirst": "Plakplaatje, Aadje"
  }],
  "photos": [{
    "metadata": {
      "primary": true,
      "source": {
        "type": "CONTACT",
        "id": "16f2742f887bd926"
      }
    },
    "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/V8BNOaftJmYAp2p_Gru2GDD5qNFKgOOLwCLcDEAEiGQoBQRD___________8BGKevgvj______wE/s100/photo.jpg",
    "default": true
  }],
  "emailAddresses": [{
    "metadata": {
      "primary": true,
      "source": {
        "type": "CONTACT",
        "id": "16f2742f887bd926"
      }
    },
    "value": "aadje@plakplaatje.nl",
    "type": "home",
    "formattedType": "Home"
  }],
  "phoneNumbers": [{
    "metadata": {
      "primary": true,
      "source": {
        "type": "CONTACT",
        "id": "16f2742f887bd926"
      }
    },
    "value": "0612345678",
    "canonicalForm": "+31612345678",
    "type": "mobile",
    "formattedType": "Mobile"
  }],
  "memberships": [{
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "16f2742f887bd926"
        }
      },
      "contactGroupMembership": {
        "contactGroupId": "21e13ce28d82ed54",
        "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/21e13ce28d82ed54"
      }
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "16f2742f887bd926"
        }
      },
      "contactGroupMembership": {
        "contactGroupId": "myContacts",
        "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/myContacts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "userDefined": [{
    "metadata": {
      "primary": true,
      "source": {
        "type": "CONTACT",
        "id": "16f2742f887bd926"
      }
    },
    "key": "shoot type",
    "value": "gezin"
  }]
}
```

Comment: From Review: I believe you mentioned about screenshots which you forgot to include in your question. Would you please add them? I also could not understand where exactly your conversation with zapier begins and where it ends. Please, try to improve the formatting of your question to make it clear.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpXzE.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yflCk.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9TVX.png